# .click(function() on link issue

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a this code I'm trying to use on my site. the problem is that whenever I click on other links in the same page that flip event is triggered. How do I correct that behavior?

```
<a href='#'>Click Me</a>

<div id='flip-container'>
    <div id='flip-card'>
        <div class='front face'>
            <div class='input-append'>
                <input style='position: static' type='text' value='front face' readonly/> <span class='add-on'>
                    <i class='icon-th'></i>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='back face'>back face</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('#flip-card').toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9CHEb/1/).

Comment: Since you have certain links you want to trigger the event for you should give those links a class and assign the click event based on that class.

Comment: The message that comes up, stopping you posting a link to JS Fiddle without code in the question, should be heeded, not worked around. Add your relevant code to your question. This time I'll assume you're new to the site, and help you out. In future, please don't repeat this mistake.

Comment: You just need to add something that differentiates that one anchor from all the rest. You can use a class, ID, data bind, whatever you like. I would suggest an id if it is the only one that will change that link. like if your id was id="swings" it would be $( '#swings' ) instead of $( 'a' )

Comment: @David Thomas, perhaps someone should not spend 10 min wondering on how to post something. UI needs some work here...

Comment: For what it's worth, there's the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/). The UI may not be perfect (I agree), but if you have suggestions feel free to visit [meta], and make a [meta-tag:feature-request] (if the same request doesn't already exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated fiddle.PLease go to below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/9CHEb/11/

have id for a link on which you want to call toggleClass.

like this

Html:

```
<a href='#' id="clickmeId">Click Me</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#clickmeId').click(function() {
$('#flip-card').toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`other links in the same page that flip event is triggered` as you have binded handler with `a` tag. Use an id or a class

HTML

```
<a href='#' id="filpme">Click Me</a>
```

JS

```
$('#filpme').click(function() {
    $('#flip-card').toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/9CHEb/12/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically identify the `a` tag you're targeting.  This will attach a click handler to *every* `a` tag on the page:

```
$('a').click(function () { ... });
```

There are lots of ways you can target specifically that one `a`, but it's all just guessing without knowing the complete markup.  One easy thing to do would be to give it an id:

```
<a href="#" id="targetLink">Click Me</a>
```

Then you can reference it with an id selector:

```
$('#targetLink').click(function () { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the link a unique id. What you have now is that function being called on any link click. So, you want something like:

```
$('a#flipLink').click(function() {
$('#flip-card').toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

and in the html:

```
<a href='#' id="flipLink">Click Me</a>
```